# How to create a LoadBalancer on GCP with two instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer, gcp-load-balancer

I have a situation here.

I made 2 environments prod and preprod, both has two vms each (like two nodes per environment).
Now i have to create a Load Balancer keeping those to nodes on the back end. Once of the nodes has SSL configured with a domain name (say example.com).

Its a Pega App Server with two nodes pointing to the same DB on Google SQL. now Client wants a Load Balancer in the front which will share or balance the traffic between these two nodes.
Is that possible?

If yes, the domain name has been registered with the ip of Node1, but Load Balancer will have a different ip right?
So if the Pega URL that was working before https://example.com/prweb will not work, isnt it?
But the requirement is they will just type the domain name and ill access the Pega App via Load balancer, as in, to which Node the requests gonna go.

Is that Possible at all guys?

Guys honestly i am a noob in all these Cloud thing, please if possible help me out. I ould really appriciate it. Thanks.

I tried to create an HTTPS Load Balancer classic and added those two instances in the Backend, but 1 target pool detected out of 2 instances, its showing "instance xxxx is unhealthy for [the ip of the load balancer]

So next i created HTTPS type Load Balancer with Network endpoint group, where i added those two nodes private ip. But not sure how to do it. Please let me know if anybody knows how to do it.

Comment: The HTTPS load balancer is the correct way, but you have to create an health check to help the load balancer to know the healthy node to route the traffic. Like that, in case of maintenance or update you will be able to route the traffic only to the up node

Comment: But i am unable to add both the nodes. One of them is showing green but the other one is showing unhealthy. Not sure how it is unhealthy, dont know where to check and what to fix. Any cluee?

Comment: your health check call something on your node. Be sure that this things answer correctly on the VM.